# Seperate country and city using php and html

Tags: php, html, timezone

This is how the  code works using drop down / select  Countries - Cities - (timezone) My problem is how to seperate the cities and the timezone from the country.

Please kindly help me.

```html
html code
<label for="timeZone"><br>City<br />
  <select id="timeZone" name="timeZone">
   <?php echo displayTimeZoneSelect("Europe/Amsterdam"); 
   ?>
  </select>
 </label>
```

```js
 PHP CODE
    /**
     * returns a HTML formated TimeZone select
     *
     * @param $selectedTimeZone string The timezone marked as "selected"
     * @return string
     */

    function displayTimeZoneSelect($selectedTimeZone = 'America/New_York'){
     $countryCodes = getCountryCodes();
     $return = null;
     foreach ($countryCodes as $country => $countryCode) {
      $timezone_identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY,$countryCode);
      foreach( $timezone_identifiers as $value ){
       /* getTimeZoneOffset returns minutes and we need to display hours */
       $offset = getTimeZoneOffset($value)/60;
       /* for the GMT+1 GMT-1 display */
       $offset = ( substr($offset,0,1) == "-" ? " (GMT" : " (GMT+" ) . $offset . ")";
       /* America/New_York -> America/New York */
       $displayValue = (str_replace('_',' ',$value));
       /* Find the city */
       $ex = explode("/",$displayValue);
       $city = ( ($ex[2]) ? $ex[2] : $ex[1] );
       /* For the special names */
       $displayValue = htmlentities($country." - ".$city.$offset); 
       /* handle the $selectedTimeZone in the select form */
       $selected = ( ($value == $selectedTimeZone) ? ' selected="selected"' : null );
       $return .= '<option value="' . $value . '"' . $selected . '>'
        . $displayValue
        . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;   
      }
     }
     return $return;
    }


    function getCountryCodes(){
    $return = array(
    "Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)"=>"AF",
    "Åland Islands (Åland)"=>"AX",
    "Albania (Shqipëri"=>"AL",
    "Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)"=>"DZ",
    "American Samoa"=>"AS",
    "Andorra"=>"AD",
    "Angola"=>"AO",
    "Anguilla"=>"AI",
    "Antarctica"=>"AQ",
    "Antigua and Barbuda"=>"AG",
    "Argentina"=>"AR",
    "Armenia (Հայաստան)"=>"AM",
    "Aruba"=>"AW",
    "Ascension Island"=>"AC",
    "Australia"=>"AU",
    "Austria (Österreich)"=>"AT",
    "Azerbaijan (Azərbaycan)"=>"AZ",
    "Bahamas"=>"BS",
    "Bahrain (‫البحرين‬‎)"=>"BH",
    "Bangladesh (বাংলাদেশ)"=>"BD",
    "Barbados"=>"BB",
    "Belarus (Беларусь)"=>"BY",
    "Belgium (België)"=>"BE",
    "Belize"=>"BZ",
    "Benin (Bénin)"=>"BJ",
    "Bermuda"=>"BM",
    "Bhutan (འབྲུག)"=>"BT",
    "Bolivia"=>"BO",
    "BONAIRE, SINT EUSTATIUS AND SABA"=>"BQ",
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina"=>"BA",
    "Botswana"=>"BW",
    "Bouvet Island"=>"BV",
    "Brazil (Brasil)"=>"BR",
    "British Indian Ocean Territory"=>"IO",
    "British Virgin Islands"=>"VG",
    "Brunei"=>"BN",
    "Bulgaria (България)"=>"BG",
    "Burkina Faso"=>"BF",
    "Burundi (Uburundi)"=>"BI",
    "Cambodia (កម្ពុជា)"=>"KH",
    "Cameroon (Cameroun)"=>"CM",
    "Canada"=>"CA",
    "Canary Islands (islas Canarias)"=>"IC",
    "Cape Verde (Kabu Verdi)"=>"CV",
    "Caribbean Netherlands"=>"BQ",
    "Cayman Islands"=>"KY",
    "Central African Republic"=>"CF",
    "Ceuta and Melilla"=>"EA",
    "Chad "=>"TD",
    "Chile"=>"CL",
    "China (中国)"=>"CN",
    "Christmas Island"=>"CX",
    "Clipperton Island"=>"CP",
    "Cocos (Keeling) Islands"=>"CC",
    "Colombia"=>"CO",
    "Comoros (‫جزر القمر‬‎)"=>"KM",
    "Congo (Republic)"=>"CG",
    "Congo (DRC)"=>"CD",
    "Cook Islands"=>"CK",
    "Costa Rica"=>"CR",
    "Côte d’Ivoire"=>"CI",
    "Croatia"=>"HR",
    "Cuba"=>"CU",
    "Curaçao"=>"CW",
    "Cyprus"=>"CY",
    "Czech Republic"=>"CZ",
    "Denmark"=>"DK",
    "Diego Garcia"=>"DG",
    "Djibouti"=>"DJ",
    "Dominica"=>"DM",
    "Dominican Republic"=>"DO",
    "Ecuador"=>"EC",
    "Egypt"=>"EG",
    "El Salvador"=>"SV",
    "Equatorial Guinea"=>"GQ",
    "Eritrea"=>"ER",
    "Estonia"=>"EE",
    "Ethiopia"=>"ET",
    "Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)"=>"FK",
    "Faroe Islands"=>"FO",
    "Fiji"=>"FJ",
    "Finland"=>"FI",
    "France"=>"FR",
    "French Guiana"=>"GF",
    "French Polynesia"=>"PF",
    "French Southern Territories"=>"TF",
    "Gabon"=>"GA",
    "Gambia"=>"GM",
    "Georgia"=>"GE",
    "Germany"=>"DE",
    "Ghana"=>"GH",
    "Gibraltar"=>"GI",
    "Greece"=>"GR",
    "Greenland"=>"GL",
    "Grenada"=>"GD",
    "Guadeloupe"=>"GP",
    "Guam"=>"GU",
    "Guatemala"=>"GT",
    "Guernsey"=>"GG",
    "Guinea"=>"GN",
    "Guinea-Bissau"=>"GW",
    "Guyana"=>"GY",
    "Haiti"=>"HT",
    "Heard & McDonald Islands"=>"HM",
    "Honduras"=>"HN",
    "Hong Kong (香港)"=>"HK",
    "Hungary"=>"HU",
    "Iceland"=>"IS",
    "India"=>"IN",
    "Indonesia"=>"ID",
    "Iran (‫ایران‬‎)"=>"IR",
    "Iraq (‫العراق‬‎)"=>"IQ",
    "Ireland"=>"IE",
    "Isle of Man"=>"IM",
    "Israel"=>"IL",
    "Italy"=>"IT",
    "Jamaica"=>"JM",
    "Japan (日本)"=>"JP",
    "Jersey"=>"JE",
    "Jordan (‫الأردن‬‎)"=>"JO",
    "Kazakhstan"=>"KZ",
    "Kenya"=>"KE",
    "Kiribati"=>"KI",
    "Kosovo (Kosovë)"=>"XK",
    "Kuwait (‫الكويت‬‎)"=>"KW",
    "Kuwait (‫الكويت‬‎)"=>"KG",
    "Laos (ລາວ)"=>"LA",
    "Latvia"=>"LV",
    "Lebanon (‫لبنان‬‎)"=>"LB",
    "Lesotho"=>"LS",
    "Liberia"=>"LR",
    "Libya (‫ليبيا‬‎)"=>"LY",
    "Liechtenstein"=>"LI",
    "Lithuania"=>"LT",
    "Luxembourg"=>"LU",
    "Macau (澳門)"=>"MO",
    "Macedonia(Македонија"=>"MK",
    "Madagascar"=>"MG",
    "Malawi"=>"MW",
    "Malaysia"=>"MY",
    "Maldives"=>"MV",
    "Mali"=>"ML",
    "Malta"=>"MT",
    "Marshall Islands"=>"MH",
    "Martinique"=>"MQ",
    "Mauritania (‫موريتانيا‬‎)"=>"MR",
    "Mauritius"=>"MU",
    "Mayotte"=>"YT",
    "Mexico"=>"MX",
    "Micronesia"=>"FM",
    "Moldova"=>"MD",
    "Monaco"=>"MC",
    "Mongolia (Монгол)"=>"MN",
    "Montenegro "=>"ME",
    "Montserrat"=>"MS",
    "Morocco (‫المغرب‬‎)"=>"MA",
    "Mozambique "=>"MZ",
    "Myanmar "=>"MM",
    "Namibia "=>"NA",
    "Nauru"=>"NR",
    "Nepal (नेपाल)"=>"NP",
    "Netherlands "=>"NL",
    "New Caledonia ("=>"NC",
    "New Zealand"=>"NZ",
    "Nicaragua"=>"NI",
    "Niger"=>"NE",
    "Nigeria"=>"NG",
    "Niue"=>"NU",
    "Norfolk Island"=>"NF",
    "Northern Mariana Islands"=>"MP",
    "North Korea"=>"KP",
    "Norway"=>"NO",
    "Oman (‫عُمان‬‎)"=>"OM",
    "Pakistan (‫پاکستان‬‎)"=>"PK",
    "Palau"=>"PW",
    "Palestine"=>"PS",
    "Panama "=>"PA",
    "Papua New Guinea"=>"PG",
    "Paraguay"=>"PY",
    "Peru "=>"PE",
    "Philippines"=>"PH",
    "Pitcairn Islands"=>"PN",
    "Poland "=>"PL",
    "Portugal"=>"PT",
    "Puerto Rico"=>"PR",
    "Qatar (‫قطر‬‎)"=>"QA",
    "Réunion"=>"RE",
    "Romania "=>"RO",
    "Russia (Россия)"=>"RU",
    "Rwanda"=>"RW",
    "Saint Barthélemy"=>"BL",
    "Saint Helena"=>"SH",
    "Saint Kitts and Nevis"=>"KN",
    "Saint Lucia"=>"LC",
    "Saint Martin (FRENCH PART)"=>"MF",
    "Saint Pierre and Miquelon"=>"PM",
    "SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES"=>"VC",
    "Samoa"=>"WS",
    "San Marino"=>"SM",
    "São Tomé and Príncipe"=>"ST",
    "Saudi Arabia (‫المملكة العربية السعودية‬‎)"=>"SA",
    "Senegal "=>"SN",
    "Serbia "=>"RS",
    "Seychelles"=>"SC",
    "Sierra Leone"=>"SL",
    "Singapore"=>"SG",
    "Sint Maarten (DUTCH PART)"=>"SX",
    "Slovakia"=>"SK",
    "Slovenia"=>"SI",
    "Solomon Islands"=>"SB",
    "Somalia "=>"SO",
    "South Africa"=>"ZA",
    "South Georgia & South Sandwich Islands"=>"GS",
    "South Korea (대한민국)"=>"KR",
    "South Sudan (‫جنوب السودان‬‎)"=>"SS",
    "Spain "=>"ES",
    "Sri Lanka"=>"LK",
    "Sudan (‫السودان‬‎)"=>"SD",
    "Suriname"=>"SR",
    "Svalbard and Jan Mayen"=>"SJ",
    "Swaziland"=>"SZ",
    "Sweden "=>"SE",
    "Switzerland "=>"CH",
    "Syria (‫سوريا‬‎)"=>"SY",
    "Taiwan (台灣)"=>"TW",
    "Tajikistan"=>"TJ",
    "Tanzania"=>"TZ",
    "Thailand (ไทย)"=>"TH",
    "Timor-Leste"=>"TL",
    "Togo"=>"TG",
    "Tokelau"=>"TK",
    "Tonga"=>"TO",
    "Trinidad and Tobago"=>"TT",
    "Tristan da Cunha"=>"TA",
    "Tunisia (‫تونس‬‎)"=>"TN",
    "Turkey "=>"TR",
    "Turkmenistan"=>"TM",
    "Turks and Caicos Islands"=>"TC",
    "Tuvalu"=>"TV",
    "Uganda"=>"UG",
    "Ukraine"=>"UA",
    "United Arab Emirates"=>"AE",
    "United Kingdom"=>"GB",
    "UNITED STATES"=>"US",
    "U.S. Outlying Islands"=>"UM",
    "Uruguay"=>"UY",
    "Uzbekistan"=>"UZ",
    "Vanuatu"=>"VU",
    "Vatican City (Città del Vaticano)"=>"VA",
    "Venezuela"=>"VE",
    "Vietnam "=>"VN",
    "VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH"=>"VG",
    "VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S."=>"VI",
    "Wallis and Futuna"=>"WF",
    "Western Sahara (‫الصحراء الغربية‬‎)"=>"EH",
    "Yemen (‫اليمن‬‎)"=>"YE",
    "Zambia"=>"ZM",
    "Zimbabwe"=>"ZW");
    return $return;
    }
    /**
     * Calculates the offset from UTC for a given timezone
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    function getTimeZoneOffset($timeZone) {
     $dateTimeZoneUTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
     $dateTimeZoneCurrent = new DateTimeZone($timeZone);
     $dateTimeUTC = new DateTime("now",$dateTimeZoneUTC);
     $dateTimeCurrent = new DateTime("now",$dateTimeZoneCurrent);
     $offset = (($dateTimeZoneCurrent->getOffset($dateTimeUTC))/60);
     return $offset;
    }
```

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you need to split something like `Europe/Amsterdam` by the `/` to get `Europe` and `Amsterdam` in 2 variables?

Comment: @JayS. Yes, Exactly.Then when you pick a country  the content of the city  will generate or load another select option with the timezone.

Comment: @JayS. Yes, Exactly.Then when you pick a country the content of the city will generate or load another select option with the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood your question.

You will need to use javascript to achieve your goal. After sending the timezone to the server, you will need to encode an array of cities in JSON format and echo it back to the client. The client will then capture that response and populate another select field.

I would recommend using jQuery AJAX.

Comment: Thankyou for th suggestions

Comment: can you please give an example or a possible reference for this project . :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYx8dQr_cQ. This video is a good intro. When he talks about using /api/orders, you would instead use a php file of your own that would look something like `<?php $cities = getArrayOfCities($_POST['timezone']); echo json_encode($cities);?>` Obviously, that is simplified and you would need to define the code that gets the cities given the timezone through $_POST. I know this may sound confusing at first, but just Google things, and you will get it. Feel free to PM me if you have any questions you can't find an answer to. @SasukeScend

Comment: Please upvote and accept if you found this helpful @SasukeScend